Impossible to send a message using the Microsoft Graph API
I need to automate sending messages in some teams channels. I use the POST method on endpoint
"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{teamId}/channels/{channelId}/messages"

My JSON looks like this :
"from": {
    "application": {
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.teamworkApplicationIdentity",
        "id": appId,
        "displayName": appName
    }
}

When I run this request in a Python script, I receive a 400 error and the body says "Invalid request - User is missing.". If I try to add "user" in the "from" dictionary with a valid user Id, I receive a 400 error with message "Only one of user, application, conversation or tag must be specified in identitySet".
Thus, my question is how can I send a message using my Azure App in a channel ?
I checked and my app has all the permissions needed.
If the problem come from the token, I get it from the msal library :
app = ConfidentialClientApplication(clientId, authority=f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}", client_credential=clientSecret)
result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"])


The most common way of doing that is to use a webhook see Send automated messages to Microsoft Teams using Python
With the endpoint your trying to use if its an Application that would be more for doing Migrations eg https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/graph-api/import-messages/import-external-messages-to-teams that's why the permission is called Teamwork.Migrate.All . Another way is to build your own conversation bot https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bot-conversations/bots-conversations
